# Only log to file for this specific module

Tags: python, logging

I'm using `logging` to do logging. But it I'm using a library that *also* uses the `logging` library. This is cluttering up my logfile really bad. How can I specify to only output to the logfile if I use *my* specific `logger`?

Comment: You should probably check docs of that library. Or at least tell what library you use so people here could help

Comment: Using the `discord.py` library, but that is irrelevant. The point is that the docs of the `logging` library don't make it clear how to only provide a log file for one particular logger.

Comment: Quick shot: "propagate" keyword at logger initiation? [https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects)

Comment: Evaluates to true. Setting to false does nothing